# git commands are incorrectly silent: git 2.17.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: git, ubuntu-18.04

I just upgraded my OS and `git`, and commands such as `git log`, `git diff`, and `git branch` are incorrectly silent.

```
$ git clone git@github.com:ropensci/drake
Cloning into 'drake'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 482, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (482/482), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (341/341), done.
remote: Total 35298 (delta 377), reused 205 (delta 136), pack-reused 34816
Receiving objects: 100% (35298/35298), 88.73 MiB | 13.48 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (28670/28670), done.
$ cd drake/
$ echo 123 > newfile
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        newfile

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
$ git diff 
$ git log -1
$ git branch
$ git --version
git version 2.17.1
$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS"
```

### Edit: with GIT_TRACE:

```
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git log -1
08:13:20.414948 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git log -1
08:13:20.417438 run-command.c:646       trace: run_command: unset 
GIT_PAGER_IN_USE; LESS=FRX LV=-c pager
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is pretty clear from here:

> ```
> 08:13:20.417438 run-command.c:646       trace: run_command: unset
> GIT_PAGER_IN_USE; LESS=FRX LV=-c pager
> ```

(I'm not sure why this line is broken into two like this).  The `git status` command, which worked, was *not* using your pager.  The `git clone` was also not using your pager.  However, `git branch`, `git diff`, and `git log` all *do* use your pager by default, which apparently is set to `pager`.

The `pager` command or alias on your system seems to work by reading standard input and showing nothing at all.  Hence the `master` branch listed by `git branch`, the diff if any from `git diff`, and the log listing from `git log`, were eaten by this `pager` command and thrown away, leaving you nothing to see.

Installing a new version of Git probably changed your pager back to the more common setting of `less`, instead of this broken `pager`.

Answer (score 1):

So apparently, version 2.20 of `git` was just released: https://github.com/git/git/releases. I [downloaded it](https://github.com/git/git/archive/v2.20.0.tar.gz) and [installed it from the source](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/INSTALL), and now I can see everything in the console. I still do not know what, if anything, is wrong with `git` 2.17.

Answer (score 0):

They are fine.

If you have no output there will be nothing in the terminal.

---

#### `git status`

You have created a new file and you did not add or commit it so there are no changes.

- You see this file with the `git status`

---

#### `git diff (no parameters)`

Print out differences between your working directory and the index.

---

#### `git log -1`

`git log -1` should print the last commit in your log.

Comment: I am not so sure. I have been using `git` for years, and this is the first time I have not seen output under these circumstances. The [repo I cloned](https://github.com/ropensci/drake) has a [long commit history upstream](https://github.com/ropensci/drake/commits/master), and I should be able to see those commits locally with `git log`. Likewise, `git branch` should tell me I am on the master branch, but there is no output. And, even when I edit an existing file, `git diff` should show me the `diff`, but nothing prints out.

Comment: I agree. i thought you removed the output. So noting is printed? test it with `GIT_TRACE=1 git log -1' whats the output?

Comment: Yes, no output, thanks. I removed nothing. Please see the edit above.